# How do I get my Apache virtual hosts working?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, windows-vista, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up virtual hosts for local development and can't seem to get it working.

I have this in my httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot C:/Users/Elliot/dev/UniServer/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName drupal.dev
 DocumentRoot C:/Users/Elliot/dev/UniServer/www/drupal.dev/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

and this in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       drupal.dev
```

`http://localhost` resolves OK, http://drupal.dev/ does not.

Any ideas welcomed...

---

Edit: I'm pretty sure that my hosts file is the underlying problem and that any edits are being ignored.

Oddly, I can edit, save and delete it without elevated permissions, which should not be the case on Windows >= Vista.

Am working through 'What can cause a DNS lookup to ignore a hosts file entry?', 'HOSTS file being ignored' and 'Problem with the hosts file in Windows XP (as a new user I can't post links).

---

Edit: in my case, stopping the DNS Client service resolved the issue....

---

Edit: ...but only very briefly.

Comment: Looks good to me.Reboot your machine :)

Comment: Done, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a ping of drupal.dev and make sure its resolving to your machine. Also, try setting the documentRoot to the same as the one above (C:/Users/Elliot/dev/UniServer/www/) just in case it's a premissions issue.

Comment: Hmm, ping fails. Any ideas?

Comment: If a ping fails- it means your host entry is not working properly- I would check this.

Comment: OK, pretty sure it's a hosts problem, which is a different question. Have edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-name-based-virtualhost-example/

Set the IP address for the NameVirtualHost and then replace the * for each VirtualHost with the qualified name (localhost for the first and drupal.dev for the second).

Comment: Make sure you add a ServerAlias as well for drupal.dev to: 
ServerAlias *drupal.dev

Comment: Thanks but as per AliGibbs' answer, it looks like the underlying issue issue is with the hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `drupal.dev` on the same line as `localhost` in your hosts file, e.g:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost drupal.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this entry :

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

It allows you to enable the vHosts

Comment: Yes, in my question, it's the first line I quote from httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Just another example how I got it working with Uniserver. My pseudo domain is "memelpower.lc" and the root you can see below.

In `C:\uniserver\core\apache2\conf\httpd.conf` you add this to the end of the file:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@memelpower.lc
    DocumentRoot "C:/uniserver/www/memelpower/public/"
    ServerName memelpower.lc
    ServerAlias memelpower.lc
    ErrorLog "C:/uniserver/www/memelpower/public/error_log"
    CustomLog "C:/uniserver/www/memelpower/public/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` you add this line in the end:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost memelpower.lc
```

Restart Apache and it should work.